# YouTube view results by view count using a shortcut string

Tags: youtube

I understood that YouTube search bar adds filters by typing text into it like "People, long, week, hd" gives me videos related to people that are uploaded this week and that are HD.

What should I type such that it gives me results by video_view_count?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Chrome, you can configure a custom search engine so that you can get results by directly typing your search keyword in the address bar or "omnibox".

Go to the YouTube site, right-click within the search box and select **Add As Search Engine...** from the context menu.

In the dialog box that appears, the text boxes will be pre-filled. You can choose to change the value for the URL box to this -
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_sort=video_view_count&search_query=%s

You can change the value for the **Keyword** box to *YT* (or any other abbreviation) instead of youtube.com. When you wish to search for a video on YouTube, type YT in the Chrome address bar and then press space or tab followed by the keywords you want to search by.